# restriction about leaving with visitor visa an comback with short term student visa?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, student-visa

My name is Paula.  I am Colombian.  I have stayed in the United Kingdom with a tourist visa for 5 months of the permitted 6 months.  Now I want to go back to Colombia and apply for a student visa, to follow a course of study in the UK.

Can I leave with my tourist visa and come back in a month with a student visa? If so, can it be the short term student or the tier 4?

Comment: Have stayed where? The destination country is very relevant here.

Comment: hello im sorry ...you are rigth... i have visitor uk visa.. and im planning to comeback as short term student

Answer (score 2):

If the visa is granted, you will be able to enter.  If your 5-month stay in the UK makes you ineligible to enter, then your visa application will be denied.

This will be true regardless of whether you apply for a short-term student visa or a Tier 4 visa.

Since the eligibility requirements do not make reference to previous stays in the United Kingdom, I suspect that your earlier trip to the UK will not have a significant effect on the success of your application.

https://www.gov.uk/tier-4-general-visa/eligibility
https://www.gov.uk/study-visit-visa/eligibility

Comment: Yup. It's common/understood that sometimes people visit the UK before applying for a student visa, to see if they like the country, or to visit universities. I entered and exited the UK twice before applying for my student visa.

Comment: @lafemmecosmique but for five months? That's a long time. I can understand why someone would be concerned about it.

Comment: Well, you haven't done anything wrong LEGALLY because you stayed less than six months. At the same time, the UK has been nabbing people for not doing things that are necessarily illegal but secretly frowned upon.
Still, at the same time, as long as you haven't been secretly working, and have been spending money in the UK, they should be happy that you left before the 6 mos. 
In any case, no way for you to know. Apply for your student visa.

Comment: With tier 4, they care that you a) Have a CAS and b) have money to support yourself presented in an obvious, unfakeable way. They care that your CAS is from a reputable institution and that you haven't committed any crime. Those *seem* to be the main things they look for.

Comment: You may have more difficulty if you are applying for a T4 from e.g. a sixth-form college or similar, and not a red-brick university.

Comment: @lafemmecosmique (delayed reply; was on vacation) If I understand correctly, that which is "secretly frowned upon" is generally something that could indicate an ulterior motive.  For example, someone who arranges a course of study after spending five months in the UK on a six-month tourist visa might be suspected of trying to settle in the UK somehow.  Such a person might have a boyfriend or girlfriend in the country and be trying to build up a family life with that person.